# .net possible to determine how much memory a collection object is using during a debugging session?

Tags: .net

I have a collection of List where the object collection is a strong typed custom object I created, I have around 300 objects in the collection.

Is it possible for me to determine how much memory this particular list is using while stepping through code during a debugging session.

Comment: By "at runtime", do you mean using the framework itself?

Comment: @Biozinc - My mistake - What I meant was during debugging.

Comment: Accepted answer is already included in my suggested answer/link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can get is [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/index.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/screenshots/20/diff.gif))</sub>

If its for performance then

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/screenshots/20/cpuSnapshot.gif))</sub>

Worth every penny

Answer (score 0):

You could use a memory profiler, such as [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/). MS also have a free [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en), but I'm not sure if it shows memory allocation as I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any free and still useful alternatives?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the comment as you posted. I don't know of any other free alternative. If it's just for a quick project, you can use it for 14 days.

Comment: No idea... I upvoted all answers... I think someone randomly downvoted every answer....

Comment: No worries. I just thought the tools weren't relevant or something :)